# ¿Cómo mantener el texto seleccionado en un EditText cuando pierde el foco?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un `EditText` y una `ToolBar` con un botón que tiene que poner mayúsculas el texto seleccionado, pero me encuentro que cuando selecciono el texto y voy a pulsar el botón de la `ToolBar`, pierde la selección.

En cambio si pulso el `floatingAcitionButton` no pierde la selección el `EditText` y puedo obtener el texto selecionado con:

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_content);

int startSelection= et != null ? et.getSelectionStart() : 0;
int endSelection= et != null ? et.getSelectionEnd() : 0;

if (et != null) {
    String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + selectedText);
}
```

Sabéis cómo se hace para mantener la selección del texto en un EditText, al pulsar otro elemento que le haga perder el foco?

Comment: Webserveis , el widget de boton en realidad no requiere enfoque, el EditText si por el texto que contiene, lo que deseas es que si das clic a otro ediText el otro mantenga el texto seleccionado? si es así no podrías escribir en el segundo EditText. Comentamé si eso deseas amigo.

Comment: Buenas, ya lo he solucionado, a veces no se explicarme y no encontraba ningún gif o animación para ilustrar, saludos

Comment: Que bien que lo solucionaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando he encontrado ese código que se debe poner dentro de un control personalizado que extienda de un `EditText`

La idea es bien simple, cuando detecta un cambio de foco guarda la posición inicio y final, hace el cambio de foco y selecciona de nuevo el texto.

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText{

    private static final String TAG = "MyEditText";

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged: ");
        boolean hadSelection = this.hasSelection();
        int start=0, end=0;
        if(hadSelection) {
            start = getSelectionStart();
            end = getSelectionEnd();
        }
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        if(hadSelection) {
            setSelection(start, end);
        }
    }

}
```

Con eso solvento que el texto si se selecciona y después se pulse sobre un botón de la `ActionBar`, mantenga el texto seleccionado el `EditText`